Github Actions upload-artifact is throwing a Syntax Error in Windows
I have the following code made to try and initialize the process of uploading files to Azure.
    - name: checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: print
      run: Compress-Archive -Path ${{ github.workspace }}/cdisc-json/* -Destination ${{ runner.temp }}/${{ github.run_id }}-cdisc-json.zip
    - name: Excel load files
      run: Compress-Archive -Path ${{ github.workspace }}/cdisc-excel/* -Destination ${{ runner.temp }}/${{ github.run_id }}-cdisc-excel.zip
    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
      with:
        name: drop
        path: "${{ runner.temp }}"

which is then providing this error when running locally using https://github.com/nektos/act?tab=readme-ov-file
 gh act -P windows-latest=-self-hosted --input ENV="dev"

...

|   static {
|          ^
|
| SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'
|     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
|     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
|     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
|     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
|     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
|     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
|     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

Is this a platform specific error from using windows, the act runner, or from the specific version of action/checkout?
